# How do I query for data indexed as IndexEmbedded(FullText in nhibernate.search)

Tags: .net, nhibernate, search, nhibernate.search

How do I query for data added as IndexEmbedded?
I have an entity class

```
  [Indexed]
  public class Something
  {
    [Field(Index.Tokenized, Store = Store.Yes)]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    [IndexedEmbedded]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    [IndexedEmbedded]
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
  }
```

Location as

```
[Indexed]
  public class Location 
  {
    /// </summary>            
    [Field(Index.Tokenized, Store = Store.Yes)]
    public virtual string Address
    {
  }
```

Data gets added(both for normal properties and IndexEmbedded) to the index and I can see them using Luke.
However when I query using Fulltext I get valid results only for the normal properties and not for **IndexedEmbedded**
*e.g.  "sample description" => 1 result, " Palo Alto" => 0 results(both of them are in the index)*
This is my query

```
using (IFullTextSession s = Search.CreateFullTextSession(NHibernateSession.GetSession())) {
        MultiFieldQuerParser qp = new MultiFieldQueryParser(new[] {
                                                                     “Description”,“Title”,”Name”
                                                                   }, new StandardAnalyzer());
        IQuery NHQuery = s.CreateFullTextQuery(qp.Parse(query), typeof(Something));
        result = NHQuery.List();
```

Am I doing something wrong or missing anything?

Answer (score 2):

From what i see, you're not referencing the fields for the IndexedEmbedded collections. You should add the following fields in your MultiFieldQueryParser

```
new MultiFieldQueryParser(new[] {"Description", "Title", "Name", "Location.Address"})
```

The correct names for the fields should be visible in Luke, prefixed with the property name you applied the *IndexedEmbedded* attribute to.

---

**edit**: If the default prefixing is not to your liking, you can change it with the prefix argument of the *IndexedEmbedded* attribute